# React - Hide menu onClick

Tags: reactjs

i'm still a beginner when it comes to react , i'm trying to create a hidden menu that slides up when you click on a button, this is my work :

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import styles from "./MenuCocktails.css";
import {BottomMenu} from "./BottomMenu";

export class BottomMenuButton extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
      super();
      this.state ={
      shown: false
    };

  }
toggleMenu(){
    this.setState({shown: !this.state.shown});
}
render(){
     return(
       <div><button onClick={this.toggleMenu.bind(this)} >My Cart</button>

          if(this.state.shown == true) {
                <BottomMenu/>
          }
          else{
             <p>Nothing to see</p>
           }

       </div>
    );
   }
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind `toggleMenu` in the constructor:

```
 constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
         shown: false
      };
      this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
  }
```

You can change you conditional logic to a one-liner:

```
{this.state.shown ? <BottomMenu /> : <p>Nothing to see</p>}
```

What's your question? What isn't working? What errors do you get?

Comment: As you can see in the image , what i wanted to do is create a button that toggles between hidden and shown content but it just loads everything instantly , also there arent any errors

Comment: Hey thank you , i had to change the if statement like you suggested , now it works , i just have to understand how to make it now into a proper menu , thanks again buddy :)